# htaccess: deliver jpg or png if browser does not accept webP

Tags: .htaccess, png, jpeg, webp, fallback

A WordPress website delivers webp. As a fallback for old browsers, jpg or png should be delivered if webp is not accepted.

Each image file is available as webp and jpg or png. With same name but different filetype.

So: image.webp plus image.jpg or image.png

With the following code I would at least like to have JPG delivered if webp is not running. But there is a problem somewhere:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !image/webp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?i)(.*)(\.webp)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.jpg -f
RewriteRule (?i)(.*)(\.webp)$ %1\.jpg [L,T=image/jpeg]
</IfModule>
```

Expected the code above to work. But it doesn't and I'm stuck now.

Can anyone help? Where is my mistake?

Edit: the code is correct now and works

Comment: Where did you put this - before WP's own rewriting?

Comment: Have you made sure the accept header does indeed not contain `image/webp`? What happens when you comment the first and third RewriteCond out, do you get redirected then?

Comment: "But it doesn't work" - What happens exactly? How are you testing this? This shouldn't be an external redirect (there should be no `R` flag on the `RewriteRule`). (It's OK to perhaps _test_ with an external redirect, but the `T` flag is not necessary for external redirects.) This rule could be optimised a bit, but otherwise it looks OK.

Comment: @CBroe "Where did you put this - before WP's own rewriting?" - Providing the requested `.webp` file actually exists then it shouldn't matter if the rule is before or after the WP code block. (In fact, it could be better placed _after_ the WP code block, so as to not be unnecessarily processed on every request.)

Comment: I think I had some typo, the code above works now. It's first in .htaccess. I removed the R. I test with the Internet-Explorer-Mode on Edge Browser.

If it is better after the WP code, I will change the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [@pixx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77893960/369434)...

> ```
> <ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !image/webp
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?i)(.*)(\.webp)$
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.jpg -f
> RewriteRule (?i)(.*)(\.webp)$ %1\.jpg [L,T=image/jpeg]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?i)(.*)(\.webp)$
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.png -f
> RewriteRule (?i)(.*)(\.webp)$ %1\.png [L,T=image/png]
> </IfModule>
> ```

You are missing the `HTTP_ACCEPT` check on the second rule. So this would result in any request for a `.webp` file, where the `.png` file also exists, serving the `.png` file instead.

However, these rules can also be simplified/optimised...

- There is no need for the *condition* that checks the `REQUEST_URI` server variable, since this only performs the same check you are already doing in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.
- You have some unnecessary *capturing* subpatterns. eg. In the regex `(?i)(.*)(\.webp)$`, the `\.webp` extension does not need to be captured (ie. enclosed in parentheses).
- No need to backslash-escape literal dots in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string (2nd argument). This is not a regex.
- The `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper is not required, unless you consider these directives entirely optional and you are copying these rules to other systems where you expect mod_rewrite to not be available.

As for where to put these rules (before or after the WordPress code block), it doesn't really matter. By placing these rules *after* the WP code block they won't be unnecessarily processed for the page request itself, which is a good thing, but it's very minor.

Bringing the above points together, the rules can be rewritten as follows...

Note that I've created an additional 1st rule that simply skips the next two rules (that perform the actual file checking/rewriting) if its not a `.webp` request OR it is a `.webp` request and `image/webp` is supported. This is an *optimisation*, since it will catch *most* requests and avoid unnecessarily processing the following two rules (that contain the "expensive" filesystem checks). So by the time we get to the second rule we already know that it must be a `.webp` request and `image/webp` is not supported.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Skip the next 2 rules if not a ".webp" request
# OR it is a ".webp" request and the client supports "image/webp"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.webp$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}@%{HTTP_ACCEPT} \.webp@.*image/webp
RewriteRule ^ - [S=2]

# Serve ".jpg" instead...
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.jpg -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.webp$ $1.jpg [NC,T=image/jpeg,L]

# Serve ".png" instead...
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.png -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.webp$ $1.png [NC,T=image/png,L]
```

You could combine this into 1 rule, but it does not make it more efficient (in fact, probably less so). And it's arguably more complex and harder to read. For example, you could do something like this instead:

```
# If ".webp" not supported then serve ".jpg" or ".png" instead...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !image/webp
RewriteCond jpg@jpeg ([^@]+)@(.+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.%1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond png@png ([^@]+)@(.+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.%1 -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.webp$ $1.%1 [NC,T=image/%2,L]
```

A (minor) downside with this rule is that there are always 2 filesystem checks if image/webp is not supported. If the corresponding ".jpg" file exists then the same filesystem check (for the ".jpg" file) is performed twice (although you would hope the 2nd check is from cache). Whereas with the multi-rule approach (shown earlier) then there are only 2 filesystem checks if image/webp is not supported and the corresponding ".jpg" file does *not* exist (in which case it tests for the ".png" file).

A slight complexity with the single rule comes about because of the difference between the `jpg` file extension and the corresponding mime-type `jpeg`. Both these need to be "stored" (the file extension in the `%1` backreference and mime-type in `%2`).

The processing of the *conditions* is reliant on the fact that the 2nd OR'd *condition* is not processed if the 1st OR'd *condition* is successful (a standard optimisation). So, in the above rule, if the first filesystem check (for a `.jpg` file) is successful then the following *condition* that sets the captured backreferences to `png` is *not* processed, so `%1` and `%2` remain as `jpg` and `jpeg` respectively, ready to be processed by the next *condition* and ultimately used in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* and *flags* arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much, @MrWhite, for your detailed explanations and the optimizations that I have just discovered.

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the code so that it can handle jpg and png:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !image/webp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?i)(.*)(\.webp)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.jpg -f
RewriteRule (?i)(.*)(\.webp)$ %1\.jpg [L,T=image/jpeg]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?i)(.*)(\.webp)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.png -f
RewriteRule (?i)(.*)(\.webp)$ %1\.png [L,T=image/png]
</IfModule>
```

It runs fine. Is there a possibility to shorten it? I tried with | (or) but had no success.

Comment: This is not quite right as you are missing the check for `image/webp` in the second rule - this could result in some unwanted rewrites to `.png` images even when the client supports `image/webp`. These rules can also be optimised. But note that "short" isn't necessarily _optimal_. I've added more detail in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77958638/369434).

Comment: You are right. In my case, however, the alternative to webp is either jpg or png. There are never jpg and png.